# R: Change row order

Tags: r

Assume a dataframe constructed like

```
df = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:10,2,rep=TRUE)))
df = t(df)
df
```

which returns something like

```
   [,1] [,2]
X1    9    8
X2   10    4
```

Here's the question: How can I change the order of rows so that:

```
   [,1] [,2]
X2   10    4
X1    9    8
```

? Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One way to do it is to index the row directly:

```
df[c("X2","X1"),]
```

Or you could use the row indices:

```
df[c(2,1),]  # or just df[2:1,]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also try

```
df[nrow(df):1,]
```

This arranges the rows in reverse order for any dataframe `df`.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you want to switch the `8` and `9` rows. The data frame has `n` rows in total.

```
mydata[c(1:7,9,8,10:nrow(mydata)), ] # new order
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
Subset(nameofthedataframe,Select = c(Namelist))
```